# How to move label in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to move a label's position in order to show the blue polygon as pictured below. The label crosses other polygons (the blue polygon) that I must present in the map. The label is part of another polygon that I don't show in the map and only show it label (number 3922).

[image]

My goal is to move the label (3922), so the blue line polygon will be shown clearly. How can I do this in ArcGIS?

[image]

I know how to edit it by:

1. convert it to graphics
2. convert the label to annotation

I am seeking other ways of doing this.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Maplex Label Engine](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/text/prevent-labels-from-overlapping-certain-features.htm)? I think you will need ArcGIS Pro for this though.

Comment: i changed the feature weight into 1000 (in conflict resolution tab in the maplex) but there no change

Comment: @newGIS which feature weight did you change? If you set the boundary weight of the blue polygon feature to 1000, the 3922 label should avoid it. A label class does not need to be turned on for the weight to have an effect on other label classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Joseph suggests, the Maplex Label Engine will give you more control over label placement and is available at all license levels of ArcGIS for Desktop.

You may be able to get the placement you need with the [Standard Label Engine](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/working-with-the-standard-label-engine.htm) however. What exactly do you want the label to do? Avoid the blue line or be placed along the orange line? What is the geometry of the layer with the 3922 label? Is it a line feature that follows the orange line?

If you just want to avoid the blue line, [adding a feature weight](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/weighting-labels-and-features.htm) to that label class should be enough, but we may need more information to be able to help with this problem.

Comment: jon_two i update my question